# not able to decode the string from C# HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode in javascript

Tags: c#, qtip2

I am generating html through C#

```
myStr = "<span class='red'>September 1980</span><br /><div>abcdef\nhijklm</div>";
shtml = "<span class='red' title='<pre>" + HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode(myStr, false) + "</pre>' id='" + jc.FirstOrDefault().UserId + "'>" + content + "</span>" + after;
... snip snip ...    
<%= shtml %>
```

And my jquery script for initializing qtip is:

```
$('[title!=""]').each(function(){
                    $(this).qtip({
                        hide: {
                            fixed: true, delay: 300
                        }, show: 'mouseover',
                        position: {
                            my: 'top center',
                            at: 'bottom center',
                            viewport: $(window),
                            adjust: {
                                method: 'shift shift'
                                , screen: true
                            }
                        }, style: {
                            classes: 'qtip-light', // Inherit from preset style
                            tip: 'topCenter'
                        }
                    });

                });
```

Now the tooltip is showing:
\u003cspan class=\u0027abcd\u0027 title=\u0027September 05, 2013 12:06\u0027\u003e\u003ci

How can I render the html in tooltip?
this has been eating my time and brains... please help!

*Note: please read the following before marking this question as duplicate:

I searched all the related posts, but none of the soutions worked for me. My use case is different as I am using qtip to show the string generated by javascriptstringencode.*

Answer (score 0):

I could not find any built in function to decode the data which is encoded using HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode. So I created a JS function after some research in various sites.

```js
String.prototype.replaceAll = function(str1, str2, ignore) {
  return this.replace(new RegExp(str1.replace(/([\/\,\!\\\^\$\{\}\[\]\(\)\.\*\+\?\|\<\>\-\&])/g, "\\$&"), (ignore ? "gi" : "g")), (typeof(str2) == "string") ? str2.replace(/\$/g, "$$$$") : str2);
}

function decodeJs(encodedString) {
  var decodedString = encodedString;
  decodedString = decodedString.replaceAll("\\u0026", "&");
  decodedString = decodedString.replaceAll("\\u0027", "\'");
  decodedString = decodedString.replaceAll("\\u003c", "<");
  decodedString = decodedString.replaceAll("\\u003e", ">");
  return decodedString;
}

function replaceText() {
  $("*").each(function() {
    if (!$(this).children().length) {
      $(this).text(decodeJs($(this).text())).val(decodeJs($(this).val()));
    }
  });
}
$(document).ready(replaceText);
$("html").ajaxStop(replaceText);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```